# Simple Overlay View on UIImagePickerControler.Camera

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, overlay

I am initiating a camera capture via `UIImagePickerController (sourceType = .Camera)`

I have created a simple ViewController `overlayVC` and designed it in IB

I wish to overlay `overlayVC` on top of the camera now. How do I accomplish this in swift?

I understand I need to use `UIImagePickerController.cameraOverlayView` property but this property wont take overlayVC directly. What step am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out my self:

```
let overlay = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OverlayVC")
image.cameraOverlayView = overlay?.view
```